# Golang - Ristretto Cache returning base 64

Tags: json, api, go, caching

I am encountering a problem while using ristretto cache. Indeed, i have a little api that should return me a value stored in my ristretto cache as json.

The problem is that when i call my function, the return is the json encoded in base64 and i just can't find the way to decode it.

Here is the code i have:

- Part 1: the code for initializing my ristretto cache:

```
func InitCache() {
    var err error
    ristrettoCache, err = ristretto.NewCache(&ristretto.Config{
        NumCounters: 3000,
        MaxCost: 1e6,
        BufferItems: 64,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Part 2: Putting my values in cache:

```
for _, t := range listTokensFromDB {
    b, err := json.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    ristrettoCache.Set(t.Symbol, b, 1)
}
```

Part 3: getting the value from cache

```
func getTokenInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["chain"]+vars["symbol"]
    value, found := ristrettoCache.Get(key)
    if !found {
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(value)
}
```

The result i have when i make a call to my api is:

*"eyJTeW1ib2wiOiJic2NDUllQVE8iLCJBZGRyIjoiMHgyQmNBMUFlM0U1MjQ0NzMyM0IzRWE0NzA4QTNkMTg1ODRDYWY4NWE3IiwiTHBzIjpbeyJTeW1ib2xUb2tlbiI6IkZFRyIsIlRva2VuQWRkciI6IjB4YWNGQzk1NTg1RDgwQWI2MmY2N0ExNEM1NjZDMWI3YTQ5RmU5MTE2NyIsIkxwQWRkciI6IjB4NDU5ZTJlMjQ4NGNlMDU2MWRmNTJiYzFlNjkxMzkyNDA2M2JhZDM5MCJ9LHsiU3ltYm9sVG9rZW4iOiJmQk5CIiwiVG9rZW5BZGRyIjoiMHg4N2IxQWNjRTZhMTk1OEU1MjIyMzNBNzM3MzEzQzA4NjU1MWE1Yzc2IiwiTHBBZGRyIjoiMHg3OGM2NzkzZGMxMDY1OWZlN2U0YWJhMTQwMmI5M2Y2ODljOGY0YzI3In1dfQ=="*

But i want the base64 decoded version...

If I change the value b to be string when i insert it in cache like so:

```
for _, t := range listTokensFromDB {
        b, err := json.Marshal(t)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        ristrettoCache.Set(t.Symbol, string(b), 1)
    }
```

When i get the response, i get the stringified json like this:
"{"Symbol":"bscCRYPTO","Addr":"0x2BcA1Ae3E52447323B..."

And i can't find a way to get out of this string :/

Anyone would know how i could get the real json please?

Thank you in advance and i wish u a good day!

Comment: Can you please confirm you are not inserting base64 encoded values? By printing t for example. Asking since restretto [doesn't even import](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dgraph-io/ristretto?tab=imports) the `encoding/base64` package, so it is unlikely the issue is with the library.

Comment: If `value` is of type `[]byte` then this is the expected behavior for `json.Encode` i.e. to base64 encode the value. Try `string(value)`.

Comment: Thanks for your replys.
I can't string(value) as it says it is of type []uint8.

I tried to do ristrettoCache.Set(t.Symbol, string(b), 1) but when i get this out on my browser, i get a string of my stringified json like this:

"{\"Symbol\":\"bscCRYPTO\",\"Addr\":\"0x2BcA1Ae3E52447323B..."

Which i can't get rid off so i get a simple real json response :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comments, I meant, in this line, `value` is most likely of type `[]byte` (or `[]uint8` - which is the same thing)

```
value, found := ristrettoCache.Get(key)
```

JSON encoding a `[]byte` will implicitly base64 the output - since JSON is text-based.

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(value) // <- value is of type []byte
```

Inspecting the base64 you posted (https://play.golang.org/p/NAVS4qRfDM2) the underlying binary-bytes are already encoded in JSON - so no extra `json.Encode` is needed.

Just output the raw-bytes in your handler - and set the content-type to `application/json`:

```
func getTokenInfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["chain"]+vars["symbol"]
    value, found := ristrettoCache.Get(key)
    if !found {
        return
    }

    // json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(value) // not this

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if bs, ok := value.([]byte); ok {
        _, err := w.Write(bs) //raw bytes (already encoded in JSON)

        // check 'err'
    } else {
        // error unexpected type behind interface{}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate,
Thx very much for your reply.
Thing is, ristretto is sending back an interface{} so i can't give it to the Write function as it expects a []byte.
I managed to do something by creating a custom writer that assigns the string of value to a global variable... It ugly but it's the only thing that worked until now :/

Comment: @akamob `interface{}` is a catch-all type that can store any type/value. Behind it is a concrete type/value. Since you can `json.Encode` and it becomes `base64` bytes - then it's obviously a `[]byte`. So simply type assert the value into a `[]byte` value. Updated answer to show how.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved me from a dirty code!